# What to wear to a casino in Las Vegas?

Tags: usa, clothing, las-vegas, dress-codes

I love wearing jeans and a t-shirt. Would this be an issue if I want to play in a casino in Las Vegas, USA? Do some casinos have a dress code?

Comment: They do not care about your clothes, they care about your money!

Comment: @HaLaBi they care about the money in every country, but for example in Germany there is strict dress code.

Comment: looks like they are more relaxed in the usa: http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g45963-i10-k5268288-Dress_codes_in_Casinos-Las_Vegas_Nevada.html

Comment: @Dirty-flow they have strict dress code in casinos in Germany?

Comment: The only casino I remember having a dress code was Grand Casino in Monte Carlo.

Comment: @HaLaBi AFAIK at least jacket is required

Comment: NZ ones ban jeans and require collared shirts...

Comment: @Karlson In Monte Carlo you need to sleep in a suit.

Comment: I'm not aware of any casinos have posted dress codes but every casino seems to attract a certain clientele and depending on what you wear you may be over or underdressed if you wish to fit in with the crowd.

Comment: After they take your shirt, you are shown the door.

Comment: I have been in (but only rarely gambled) the majority of the Las Vegas casinos, always in jeans and a polo.  I've also been in half a dozen shows, same attire.  A bit low compared to the average in the higher end casinos but not enough to stand out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For the general area, there's no dress code - you even see people wandering through in their swimming gear after they've been in the pool!  I've been in wearing t-shirt and jeans, feeling under-dressed until I saw the tourists in their t-shirt and shorts with flip-flops.

However, you may wish to consider what else you want to do in Vegas, and dress accordingly. Many nightclubs have dress codes, as do some of the restaurants. Night clubs in fact often suggest [business casual](http://www.lasvegasdirect.com/las-vegas-dress-code.html) - leather shoes, collared shirts, and so on.

If you're seeing a show, people *tend* to dress up for those - smart long-sleeved shirt and trousers, although again it's not a strict rule.

And if you're just wandering the streets looking, it's handy to have light clothes in summer - it can get seriously hot!

Comment: Depends on the show. :)

Comment: Thus the italics on *tend* :)

Answer (score 11):

Generally there is no strict dress code on the casino floors (within reason), so Jeans and T-Shirt would be just fine.  There is a blog entry on [the subject from Las Vegas Direct](http://www.lasvegasdirect.com/las-vegas-dress-code.html) and also on [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g45963-i10-k5268288-Dress_codes_in_Casinos-Las_Vegas_Nevada.html).  There is also a [somewhat decent FAQ](http://www.lvlg.com/faqpage.htm) regarding age restrictions.

If you get into an exclusive area where stakes are rather large you might be required to wear a suit and tie.

Comment: Definitely depends on the "classiness" of the casino.  Higher stakes = better clothes.  If the casino is part of a 5-star hotel, you'll fewer people in shorts and flip-flops, but you will still see a lot of dressy casual clothes there too.